# JPA inheritance and Dtos

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I have a project with several DTOs which can be exchanged between several loosely coupled components.

All of them have a name and a id like this:

```
public class BaseDto {
    private String id;
    private String name
}
```

Based on this there are several other DTOs which should not have any annotations for their retrieval or anything. So no jpa annotations here.

In my jpa component I want to extend the Dtos and give them annotation like this:

```
public class SomethingJpa extends SomethingDto {
   @Column(name = "someProperty")
   public String getSomeProperty() {...}      
}
```

This is to have a clean database access layer and components not depending on the JPA stuff do not have to have the full stack as dependency but I can still share all DTOs to all components (Which pass objects around in different manners sometimes JSON). As the JPA component only passes the base class versions to all other components.

This works but I can only inherit from one Class. For the JPA Context I would like to have a @MappedSuperclass annotaion so I don't have to include id and name in every JPA object.

Putting the annotations in the DTOs would mean, that I would need to put annotations for 3+ different use case methods in there making them hard to maintain. Also possible would be to just maintain all DTOs at once and always update them at the same time which is tedious. (The JSON ones only need annotations in special cases so that an updated DTO means updated JSON)

PS: See JSON just as example for any arbitrary way.